# SaveChanges Invald?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Working on a process of a pick off an imagemap that lets a user create a new record in the table. The record is generic except for one piece of data that I am supplying for it (EID) that links it to the rest of the data in the app. So this isn't rocket science really (or so I thought). I'm new (GREEN AS CAN BE) to writing C# code so I looked up some examples of what folks were using for inserts that might be fitting for this and settled on one that looked straight forward and reasonable.

The table I am using has an auto identity index so I don't even have to bother with that. As I'm typing this in referencing the example I found (here on SOF 3 years back) everything went fine till I got to the last word of the component... 'SaveChanges'!

I'm on VS 2012 Did something change? What am I doing wrong here folks? Here is my code the way I have it laid out right now.

```
            var context = new GETTEntities();
            var t = new GETT_Documents
            {
                EID = EleIDLBL.Text,
            };
            context.GETT_Documents.Add(t);
            context.GETT_Documents.SaveChanges();
```

Dosn't show it here but the SaveChagnes() is redlining telling me that I am missing a 'using' statement. Now I could put a 
using (GETTEntities Context = new GETTEntities()) 
above this, but I didn't because the example I saw didn't use that at all.
 Any advice would be appreciate.
Regards and thanks!
Ken...

Comment: SaveChanges is on context and and not on the entity set so you need `context.SaveChanges()`. (Also consider using the `using` statement for your context so that it is disposed properly)

Comment: I assume it is complaining about `SaveChanges` not being a member of `GETT_Documents`? - you didn't actually mention what is happening. Try `context.SaveChanges()`

Comment: This is not a sql-server related issue, please use tags properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
            var context = new GETTEntities();
            var t = new GETT_Documents
            {
                EID = EleIDLBL.Text,
            };
            context.GETT_Documents.Add(t);
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks guys you were spot on... I had somehow inserted .documents into context.SaveChanges(); and staring at it I just wasn't seeing it at all even though it was right in front of my face.  When I remove the ".documents" from that ran it everything was perfect.